# Cannot figure out logic flaw in traversal to check whether a tree has a particular subtree within it

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, tree, depth-first-search

I am trying to solve the following question:

Given two non-empty binary trees s and t, check whether tree t has exactly the same structure and node values with a subtree of s. A subtree of s is a tree consists of a node in s and all of this node's descendants. The tree s could also be considered as a subtree of itself.

Example 1:

```
Given tree s:
     3
    / \
   4   5
  / \
 1   2

Given tree t:
   4 
  / \
 1   2
```

Return true, because t has the same structure and node values with a subtree of s.

Example 2:

```
Given tree s:
     3
    / \
   4   5
  / \
 1   2
    /
   0

Given tree t:
   4
  / \
 1   2
```

Return false.

I have written the following code.  I believe it to be comparing trees correctly but I am not returning the correct value for the last case.

```
class TreeNode {
    constructor(val, left, right) {
        this.val = (val === undefined ? 0 : val)
        this.left = (left === undefined ? null : left)
        this.right = (right === undefined ? null : right)
    }
}

const isSubtree = (s, t) => {
    if (!s || !t) return false
    let sameTree = false

const isSubtree = (s, t) => {
    if (!s || !t) return false
    let sameTree = false

    //changed to preOrder, but it does not work for left or right skewed trees
    const dfsPO = c => {
        if (!c) return
        if (c.val === t.val) sameTree = isSameTree(c, t)
        if (c.left) dfsPO(c.left)
        if (c.right) dfsPO(c.right)
        return sameTree
    }
    return sameTree = dfsPO(s)
}

const isSameTree = (c, t) => {
    if (!c && !t) return true
    if (!c || !t) return false
    if (c.val !== t.val) return false
    return isSameTree(c.left, t.left) && isSameTree(c.right, t.right)
}
```

Here are the test cases:

```
const tree1 = new TreeNode(3, new TreeNode(4, new TreeNode(1), new TreeNode(2)), new TreeNode(5))
const tree2 = new TreeNode(4, new TreeNode(1), new TreeNode(2))

const tree3 = new TreeNode(3, new TreeNode(4, new TreeNode(1), new TreeNode(2, new TreeNode(0))), new TreeNode(5))
const tree4 = new TreeNode(4, new TreeNode(1), new TreeNode(2))

const tree5 = new TreeNode(1, new TreeNode(1))
const tree6 = new TreeNode(1)

console.log(isSubtree(tree1, tree2)) //true
console.log(isSubtree(tree3, tree4)) //false
console.log(isSubtree(tree5, tree6)) //true 

//the input for the tree that fails is as follows:

//[1,null,1,null,1,null,1,null,1,null,1,null,1,null,1,null,1,null,1,null,1,2]
//[1,null,1,null,1,null,1,null,1,null,1,2]
```

I need help figuring out where the flaw in my logic is for left or right skewed trees.

Comment: `isSameTree` doesn't always return something.

Comment: Think about what `isSameTree` returns when `c.val === t.val`.

Comment: Read what `isSameTree` will*actually* do if `c.val==t.val`.  Better yet, *test it*.

Comment: ah I see...I forgot to write the check for the child nodes.  I will update the code, but I still think the logic might be incorrect because there's another test case it will not pass for.  I will amend the question above after updating.

Answer (score 4):

What a fun question!

```js
const empty =
  {}

const tree = (v = null, l = empty, r = empty) =>
  ({ v, l, r })
```

We need two trees, `t1` and `t2` -

```
t1:
     3
    / \
   4   5
  / \
 1   2

t2:
   4
  / \
 1   2
```

We can easily write those using `tree` -

```js
const t1 =
  tree
    ( 3
    , tree(4, tree(1), tree(2))
    , tree(5)
    )

const t2 =
  tree(4, tree(1), tree(2))
```

I think you have the right idea for testing if two trees are `equal` -

1. If both `t1` and `t2` are empty, there is nothing left to compare, return true
2. By induction, both `t1` and `t2` are not empty. If `t1` xor `t2` is empty, return false
3. By induction, neither `t1` nor `t2` are empty. If `t1.v` matches `t2.v`, recur and compare each subtree

```
const equal = (t1 = empty, t2 = empty) =>
  t1 === empty && t2 === empty
    ? true                       // 1
: t1 === empty || t2 === empty
    ? false                      // 2
: t1.v === t2.v                  // 3
    && equal(t1.l, t2.l)
    && equal(t2.l, t2.r)
```

We can write `isSubTree` -

1. When `t` is empty, `s` is a subtree of `t` if `s` is empty
2. By induction, `t` is not empty. return `equal(t,s)` or recur on `t.l` or recur on `t.r`

```js
const isSubTree = (t = empty, s = empty) =>
  t === empty
    ? s === empty          // 1
    : equal(t, s)          // 2
      || isSubTree(t.l, s)
      || isSubTree(t.r, s)
```

See the code in action! Verify the results in your own browser below -

```js
const empty =
  {}

const tree = (v = null, l = empty, r = empty) =>
  ({ v, l, r })

const equal = (t1 = empty, t2 = empty) =>
  t1 === empty && t2 === empty
    ? true
: t1 === empty || t2 === empty
    ? false
: t1.v === t2.v
    && equal(t1.l, t2.l)
    && equal(t1.r, t2.r)

const isSubTree = (t = empty, s = empty) =>
  t === empty
    ? s === empty
    : equal(t, s)
      || isSubTree(t.l, s)
      || isSubTree(t.r, s)

const t1 =
  tree
    ( 3
    , tree(4, tree(1), tree(2))
    , tree(5)
    )

const t2 =
  tree(4, tree(1), tree(2))

const t3 =
  tree(4, tree(1), tree(9))

console.log(isSubTree(t1, t2)) // true
console.log(isSubTree(t1, t3)) // false
```

I hope that this approach shows you that sometimes less is more when it comes to writing programs.

---

---

**boolean logic**

This question has a good opportunity to start learning about boolean logic. If you're like me, you don't like writing conditionals like -

```js
if (someCondition)
  return true
else
  return false

return someCondition ? true : false
```

Since `someCondition` is already a boolean, in both cases it's more straightforward to write -

```js
return someCondition
```

When we wrote `equal`, we see we are returning `true` and `false` in some of the code branches. But it's not exactly easy to see how these can be cleaned up...

```js
const equal = (t1 = empty, t2 = empty) =>
  // can we collapse the explicit bools?
  t1 === empty && t2 === empty
    ? true                       // <-- explicit bool
: t1 === empty || t2 === empty
    ? false                      // <-- explicit bool
: t1.v === t2.v
    && equal(t1.l, t2.l)
    && equal(t1.r, t2.r)
```

We're don't want to be reckless and guess which logic is correct. We will approach this methodically using a truth table so we can get a reliable answer -

```
│ p := (t1 === empty)
│ q := (t2 === empty)

┌───┬───┬──────────┬───────────┬─────────┬──────────┬──────────┬───────────┐
│ p │ q │ p 'and q │ p 'nand q │ p 'or q │ p 'nor q │ p 'xor q │ p 'xnor q │
├───┼───┼──────────┼───────────┼─────────┼──────────┼──────────┼───────────┤
│ 1 │ 1 │    1     │     0     │    1    │    0     │    0     │     1     │
│ 1 │ 0 │    0     │     1     │    1    │    0     │    1     │     0     │
│ 0 │ 1 │    0     │     1     │    1    │    0     │    1     │     0     │
│ 0 │ 0 │    0     │     1     │    0    │    1     │    0     │     1     │
└───┴───┴──────────┴───────────┴─────────┴──────────┴──────────┴───────────┘
```

Referencing our truth table, we can see that `and` and `nor` perfectly describe our boolean logic -

```js
const equal = (t1 = empty, t2 = empty) =>
                                 //┌───┬───┬┬──────────┬──────────┐
                                 //│ p │ q ││ p 'and q │ p 'nor q │
                                 //├───┼───┼┼──────────┼──────────┤
  t1 === empty && t2 === empty   
    ? true                       //│ 1 │ 1 ││    1     │    0     │

: t1 === empty || t2 === empty   
    ? false                      //│ 1 │ 0 ││    0     │    0     │
                                 //│ 0 │ 1 ││    0     │    0     │

                                 //│ 0 │ 0 ││    0     │    1     │
: t1.v === t2.v                  //└───┴───┴┴──────────┴──────────┘
    && equal(t1.l, t2.l)         
    && equal(t1.r, t2.r)
```

Use of `and` matches the top two conditions and code branches; `nor` matches the final branch where we recur  -

```js
const nor = (x, y) =>
  !(Boolean(x) || Boolean(y))

const equal = (t1 = empty, t2 = empty) =>
                                  //┌───┬───┬┬──────────┬──────────┐
                                  //│ p │ q ││ p 'and q │ p 'nor q │
                                  //├───┼───┼┼──────────┼──────────┤
  nor(t1 === empty, t2 === empty) //│ 0 │ 0 ││    0     │    1     │
    ? t1.v === t2.v
        && equal(t1.l, t2.l)
        && equal(t1.r, t2.r)
    : t1 === empty && t2 === empty//│ 1 │ 0 ││    0     │    0     │
                                  //│ 0 │ 1 ││    0     │    0     │
                                  //│ 1 │ 1 ││    1     │    0     │
```

Or in plain words -

1. If neither tree is empty, the trees are equal if the value matches and the subtrees are equal
2. By induction, at least one tree is empty. The trees are equal only if both trees are empty.

```js
const equal = (t1 = empty, t2 = empty) =>
  nor(t1 === empty, t2 === empty)
    ? t1.v === t2.v                 // 1
        && equal(t1.l, t2.l)
        && equal(t1.r, t2.r)
    : t1 === empty && t2 === empty  // 2
```

NB we call `nor` before `and` (`&&`). This is because we only want to recur when *neither* tree is empty. Because `and` and `nor` return the same answer for `(p = 1, q = 0)` and `(p = 0, q = 1)`, we can only make recursion exclusive on the `nor` branch by putting it first.

Comment: @ggorlen thanks for checking. I had a false positive with my original tree inputs. You are right `{} !== {}` but `empty === empty` :D

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense and probably wasn't the reason the original was failing, although I didn't look closely.

Answer (score 1):

`isSameTree` looks OK to me. `isSubTree` is hard to follow, but basically all you have to do is walk `s` and run `isSameTree` for every subtree rooted at each node in `s`. If at any point in `isSubtree` we find that one or the other node is null, we need to check that they're both null before assuming success, which is the same logic needed in `equalTrees`.

There is room for improvement in efficiency--this seems to be `O(st)` where for every node in `s`, we check every node in `t`. The LeetCode thread has interesting optimizations including Merkle hashing and checking the max depth of each tree and only running comparisons on the one possible level where subtrees could match from. There are also stringification solutions.

```js
const equalTrees = (s, t) => {
  if (!s || !t) return s === t;
  
  return s.val === t.val && 
         equalTrees(s.left, t.left) &&
         equalTrees(s.right, t.right);
};

const isSubtree = (s, t) => {
  if (!s || !t) return s === t;
  
  return equalTrees(s, t) || 
         isSubtree(s.left, t) || 
         isSubtree(s.right, t);
};

const a = {
  val: 1,
  left: {
    val: 2,
    right: {val: 3}
  },
  right: {
    val: 4,
    left: {val: 5},
    right: {val: 6}
  }
};
const b = {
  val: 4,
  left: {val: 5},
  right: {val: 6}
};
const c = {
  val: 4,
  left: {val: 42}, // wrong val
  right: {val: 6}
};
const d = {
  val: 4,
  left: {val: 5},
  right: {
    val: 6,
    left: {val: 7} // extra child
  }
};

console.log(isSubtree(a, b));
console.log(isSubtree(a, c));
console.log(isSubtree(a, d));
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the comments above I have come up with the following solution:

```
const isSubtree = (s, t) => {
    if (!s) return false
    if (!t) return true
    if (s.val === t.val) {
        if (isSameTree(s, t)) return true
    }
    return isSubtree(s.left, t) || isSubtree(s.right, t)
}

const isSameTree = (c, t) => {
    if (!c && !t) return true
    if (!c || !t) return false
    if (c.val !== t.val) return false
    return isSameTree(c.left, t.left) && isSameTree(c.right, t.right)
}
```

Comment: I added a section on boolean logic in my updated answer. I hope you find it useful :D